# what is ?client&channel=mac_bm

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, internet, url

Macbook Pro
-Safari, preferences, general, new window opens with - Favorites.
-File, new window.
I see Favorites, right click on the google icon, click on edit address.
What I see here is https:/www.google.com/?client&channel=mac_bm. 
What is this? 
Even when I edit the address it will go back to this one.
How is this extra part starting with the ? even added on in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

It is just telling Google the type of "computer" you have.

The `client` is you and `mac` is the type of computer you have.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that part. I guess Im wondering why the google icon is the only one in favorites with this extra information added on in the url address. Im sure that Google might make my searching extra fancy with flowers if that info is attached. Where can I locate on my computer the source of the settings for favorites? Is it a folder, or terminal command?

Comment: @LisaAnn Because google wants it?? Google is probably getting from the [User Agent String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) provided by Safari.

Comment: Can I set the default (so it will stay) to be just https://www.google.com? I will look up and figure out what you say if you can tell me what to do.